# Storage efficient way to store a large python dictionary into database

Tags: python, sql, nosql

I am looking for a storage efficient way to store a python dictionary into a database.

The dictionary is large `(8 TB)`.

dictionary key: string of max `256 chars`

dictionary value: `2D` lists
The `2D` lists consists of 1 to 5 lists with `1000 float numbers` for each list.

A float precision of `2 decimal` is required.

I need fast access via dictionary key. The data will be never updated.
I am open for any database types.

Comment: How about hdf5, which you can also operate it through pandas by group keys

Comment: Should I store it as a string? I can also convert it to a 1D float array? What format needs less storage?

Comment: Look into DBM successors, like wiredtiger.